# checkout - Place order on Step 5

Tags: checkout

Is there any way to drop step 6 from the checkout and have the place order button straight on step 5. So it attempts payment immediately?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't try to remove the last step. I found this that removes the shipping address step: http://sapnandu-magento.blogspot.ro/2012/04/magento-onestep-checkout-remove.html  Maybe, following the same logic, you can drop the review step. Or (just an idea), remove the payment step and move the payment methods form in the last step.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible problematically.

you have to merge savePaymentAction() and saveOrderAction() functions